# Cannot compile simple program which uses ARM Neon for Cortex A53

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, arm64, neon, cortex-a

I am trying to cross compile a large project ([XNNPACK at this specific commit](https://github.com/google/XNNPACK/commit/ae108ef49aa5623b896fc93d4298c49d1750d9ba)) for an ARM Cortex A53 based linux system. This project uses ARMs `arm_neon.h` header and functions. While compiling, I get many errors of the same variety:

```
error: inlining failed in call to 'always_inline' 'vmaxq_f16': target specific option mismatch
| 31591 | vmaxq_f16 (float16x8_t __a, float16x8_t __b)
```

This error appears for multiple NEON functions, including `vminq_f16`, `vmulq_f16`, etc. To more easily troubleshoot, I created a simple test program which uses NEON:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

int main() {
    float16x8_t a = vdupq_n_f16(1.0f);
    float16x8_t b = vdupq_n_f16(2.0f);
    float16x8_t c = vmulq_f16(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

This program also suffers the same error when compiling with the correct architecture set on the native platform (`-march=armv8-a`) I tried compiling with `-march=armv8.2-a+fp16` option and was able to compile, but got an illegal instruction error. I have tried multiple combinations of flags to no avail. For some extra information:

The output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` gives the following (for all 4 cores available):

```
Features    : fp asimd aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
```

The presence of fp and asimd make me think this feature is available. Further, [this arm documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka005463/latest/) implies that it is highly likely NEON should be supported on a Cortex A processor. The specific processor implementation is the one found in the Xilinx Zynq Ultrascale+ MPSoC. [Xilinx documentation for this MPSoC](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1085-zynq-ultrascale-trm/Advanced-SIMD-and-Floating-point-Extension) also implies that this NEON functionality should be present:

> Advanced SIMD and floating-point extension implements Arm NEON technology... Advanced SIMD instructions are available in AArch64 and AArch32 states.

## Main Questions:

At this point I am not sure if I should be trying to get the project to compile without those functions, as they are not supported on my CPU, or if they are supported and I am missing compiler options or something else. Any help in either of those directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Cortex-A53` is `armv8`, **not**  `armv8.2`. `armv8` doesn't support `fp16`

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I see now that in `arm_neon.h` there are additional `GCC target ("arch=armv8.2-a+fp16")` added for the fp16 functions, I did not realize that `neon` had 'optional' subsets of functionality, for lack of better words. Thank you for clarifying this for me. If you would like to post that as an answer I would accept it as you've directly answered my question of if this is an issue with compiler options or hardware support.